# how to retrieve a value from a div in html file using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

```
 <li class="col-xs-12 padding-lr-reset">
                                <div class="left-header pull-right padding-left-title">
                                    GPU
                                </div>
                                <div class="right-description width-li-spec pull-right ltr text-align-right">
                                    Adreno 405
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

I', using import.io to retrieve mobile specification from a table in a persian website but problem is some fields and values always moves in other phone's specifications.for example ,I'm trying to use xpath to find any value for gpu field in whole table.

Sorry for my bad English !

[here is the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMJdz.jpg)

Comment: Could you post your html please ?

Comment: the code is in image link in end of the post but i post it directly asap

Comment: which value would you like to extract ?

Comment: i'm looking for gpu value as I selected in image and I want to use xpath code for other fields.

Comment: original url [link]http://www.gsm.ir/item/mobile/show/26612/%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84-Samsung-Galaxy-C5/)

Comment: Okay I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the required value, here is the xpath:

```
normalize-space(.//div[normalize-space(.) = 'GPU']/following-sibling::div[1]/text())
```

Where `div[normalize-space(.)='GPU']` search for all the div nodes that its *clean* text is equal to `GPU`, and `following-sibling::div[1]` takes the first div node after those nodes that normalize-space(.) = 'GPU' has returned

I tested it and it gives :

```
u'Adreno 405
```

Comment: it works without normalize-space !!! I paste this phrase >> .//div[normalize-space(.) = 'GPU']/following-sibling::div[1]/text() and it worked. thanks

Comment: can I use it for other fields? because I want to use this pattern for all fields one by one.

Comment: @mehdiMalek the normalize space is just to remove the whitespaces. and yes you can use it as long as the HTML is the same

Comment: Thanks a lot @William Kinaan but i afraid not. Because there where at least 2 "TYPE" nodes,first one for screen section, second one for  os section. It makes a conflict. FYI "type" in farsi language is "نوع".

Comment: Please ask a new question, and I'll try to help

Comment: Already done.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623284/retriving-value-from-same-nodes-in-html

Comment: @mehdiMalek Alright, it's Friday night here, I'll look tomorrow morning